# Open Excel Spreadsheet (.xlsx) with Python

Tags: python, excel

I get hundreds of automatically generated excel files from a customer. I'm Pretty sure that they are generated using data from an SQL website database. I then merge these files into one and upload to access database to which a different software is connected that pulls the information and creates Artwork from it. For some reason because the Excel file is never open by a user the data that comes through comes with some irregularities with spaces etc.

To fix this I wrote a simple python program that opens a file in a folder, Saves it and closes, then a next file is opened - this is repeated for every file in that Folder.

I tried using various Excel parsers available
such as openpyxl - with no luck - as it doesn't actually save it like a real user would. 
I also tried simple open(excelFile w/r) with same result.

The issue I think is that the Excel file generated by the online portal is a different version (not 100% sure)

```py
import os
import time
Path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/PythonFiles/New folder/"
filelist = os.listdir(Path) 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
for i in filelist:
    myPath= "C:/Users/username/Desktop/PythonFiles/New folder/" +  i
    os.startfile(myPath)
    time.sleep(3)
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press('s')
    keyboard.release('s')
    keyboard.press('w')
    keyboard.release('w')
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
```

Now my question. Does anybody know of a way where I can open each of these files like I do here - but not use a timer, instead check when the program has fully opened and then do the 'ctrl+s, ctrl+w). I ask because I cant seem to find a perfect time for it to work. sometimes it takes excel more than 3 sec to open causing it to not close properly.

Comment: While excel formats are numerous, I see no substantial information to deduce, what subset you require. (*With no luck* is not the level of details for thinking about a solution.)

Comment: You could write an Autoit script for that. Should be less than 10 lines of code

Comment: Sorry, the format is .xlsx

Comment: how do we know that your files that are so corrupt that standard python spreadsheet parsers cannot open them will actually work with MS software?

Comment: The files are not corrupted. I can open them just fine. The file are later used with a software called NiceLabel - which looks at each cell in the excel database and from it populates the variables. But for some reason Unless the file has been previously opened by a user and simply saved the data that NiceLabel pulls is different. (It adds carriage returns after data) - Eg. (Hello - becomes Hello <CR><CR><CR>) CR = carriage return

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is not Python, but maybe it helps you out. (Autoit - autoitscript.com)

```
#include <File.au3>
#include <Excel.au3>
Local $files_A = _FileListToArray('C:/Users/username/Desktop/PythonFiles/New folder/', '*.xlsx',  $FLTA_FILES, True)
;~ _ArrayDisplay($files_A) ; show all the files found
Local $oExcel = _Excel_Open(False, True, True, True, True)
For $i = 1 To 5 ; UBound($files_A) -1
    $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookOpen($oExcel, $files_A[$i])
    $oWorkbook.Saved = False
    _Excel_BookSave($oWorkbook)
    _Excel_BookClose($oWorkbook, True)
    If @error Then MsgBox(16, 'ERROR', 'Saving ...')
Next
_Excel_Close($oExcel)
```

Comment: This will change the modified timestamp of the files.